# AWS CodeBuild identifies build as success in spite of test cases failing

Tags: continuous-integration, aws-codebuild

I am new to AWS CodeBuild. I am trying to run some cucumber-js test cases  using CodeBuild. After the execution of tests, I get the results of the test cases printed out in the console and logs (CloudWatch).

What I am observing is that irrespective of the test results, the buildStatus always shows as succeeded and in the logs, it says 'Phase complete: BUILD Success: true'. This is not desired since I need the build phase to fail.

**Here is part of the log file output:**

46 scenarios (4 failed, 42 passed)
317 steps (4 failed, 4 skipped, 309 passed)
0m24.718s
going to kill process
tests completed

[Container]  Phase complete: BUILD Success: true

As you can see, the build says success: true in spite of the fact that some of the tests failed.

I am not using a buildspec.yml since that is optional. I use a shell script to do the tests like so:

node ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js --format-options '{"colorsEnabled":false}'

Any help would be appreciated.. Thanks!

Comment: CodeBuild identifies failures based on exit code of the command itself. Can you validate locally what is the exit code of this command when it fails?

Comment: Ah,  I didn't realise that CodeBuild uses exit code of the program you run. Well in my case the node command was returning the proper error code, but I wasn't feeding it back to CodeBuild from the shell script I was using. Thanks again! That resolved my issue :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using a shell script instead of buildspec.yml and was not passing the return code of the node command back to CodeBuild from the script. So there was no way for CodeBuild to understand if there was any failure. When I captured the exit code and returned it from the script, it started identifying the test failures.

node ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js --format-options '{"colorsEnabled":false}

exitcode=$?; 
exit $exitcode;

Thanks to the comment made by awsnitin, I could resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you know, how I can capture exit code when executing from buildspec ?